# OpenShift idle state issue

Tags: openshift

I have issues with my app: when it goes in the "idle" state and then goes back to the "started" state, it messes up one of my cartridges. Basically a PID file is not removed, so I have to delete it manually before restarting the cartridge. This PID file is removed when stopping the cartridge manually.

So I am wondering: what happens when the app goes in the "idle" state? Is it equivalent to stopping the app manually? Which cartridge scripts are executed when that happens?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may try the web console restart command.
But mostly the force restart from the rhc command tools renders better results.

http://www.howtech.ga